# Sampling from degree distribution of graph

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a simple, stupid Python problem. Given a graph, I'm trying to sample from a random variable whose distribution is the same as that of the degree distribution of the graph.

This seems like it should pretty straightforward. Yet somehow I am still managing to mess this up. My code looks like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import graph_tool.all as gt

G = gt.random_graph(500, deg_sampler=lambda: np.random.poisson(1), directed=False)
deg = gt.vertex_hist(G,"total",float_count=False)

# Extract counts and values
count = list(deg[0])
value = list(deg[1])

# Generate vector of probabilities for each node
p = [float(x)/sum(count) for x in count]

# Load into a random variable for sampling
x = sp.stats.rv_discrete(values=(value,p))
print x.rvs(1)
```

However, upon running this it returns an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp.py", line 16, in <module>
    x = sp.stats.rv_discrete(values=(value,p))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/stats/distributions.py", line 5637, in __init__
    self.pk = take(ravel(self.pk),indx, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 103, in take
    return take(indices, axis, out, mode)
IndexError: index out of range for array
```

I'm not sure why this is. If in the code above I write instead:

```
x = sp.stats.rv_discrete(values=(range(len(count)),p))
```

Then the code runs fine, but it gives a weird result--clearly the way I've specified this distribution, a value of "0" ought to be most common. But this code gives "1" with high probability and never returns a "0," so something is getting shifted over somehow.

Can anyone clarify what is going on here? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You say "if I write instead" but you copy down the same line, should there be a different line?

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. I've made the edit.

Comment: Does `range(len(count))` have the same values as `value`?

Comment: I believe it does. It lists from 0 up to max degree in the graph, which is what `value` should return as well. But let me double check...

Comment: Yes, it does. But no matter, your solution below fixed the problem. I'm still not sure what the error message is exactly saying, but hey, whatever works...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the first argument for `x.rvs()` would be the `loc` arg.  If you make `loc=1` by calling `x.rvs(1)`, you're adding `1` to all values.

Instead, you want

```
x.rvs(size=1)
```

---

As an aside, I'd recommend that you replace this:

```
# Extract counts and values
count = list(deg[0])
value = list(deg[1])

# Generate vector of probabilities for each node
p = [float(x)/sum(count) for x in count]
```

With:

```
count, value = deg       # automatically unpacks along first axis
p = count.astype(float) / count.sum()  # count is an array, so you can divide all elements at once
```

Comment: I may be mistaken, but earlier versions of python might force a hidden integer division on your normalization. You may want to cast (`.astype`) an array to a floating point representation.

Comment: Thanks @Hooked, done.  An alternative solution would be `from __future__ import division` which is what I usually use.

Comment: Ah, this is great. Thanks for clearing that up. I should've paid more attention to the documentation. Anyways, you're helping me a lot. I appreciate it!